# Getting Dispose exception for DbContext in .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

Im new to c# and .net core

Im doing a project on .NET core web api 3.1 and EntityFramework

I have a repository package and applying Generic Repository Pattern. In this package i have IRepository Interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    void InsertObject(T obj);
    void DeleteObject(int objId);
    void UpdateObject(T obj);
    T GetObjectById(int obj);
    IEnumerable<T> GetObjectList();
}
```

Then I have Repository class that implements that Interface:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ClothingContext dbContext;

    public Repository(ClothingContext clothing)
    {
        dbContext = clothing;
    }
    public void Insert(int objId){
        var obj = dbContext.Set<T>().Find(objId);
        dbContext.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T GetObjectById(int obj)
    {
        return dbContext.Set<T>().Find(obj);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetObjectList()
    {
        var originalObjects = dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
        return originalObjects;
    }

    public void InsertObject(T obj)
    {
        dbContext.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void UpdateObject(T obj)
    {
        dbContext.Entry(obj).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void DeleteObject(int objId)
    {
        var obj = dbContext.Set<T>().Find(objId);
        dbContext.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

After, I have a specific model repo class

```
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>
{
    private static ProductRepository productRepository;
    public ProductRepository(ClothingContext clothingContext) : base(clothingContext)
    {
    }

    public static ProductRepository GetInstance(ClothingContext clothing)
    {
        if(productRepository == null)
        {
            productRepository = new ProductRepository(clothing);
        }
        return productRepository;
    }
}
```

This class will in future have its own methods. In there I only applying a singleton pattern.

ConfigureService method in Startup class is like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ClothingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ClothingApp11270")));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddTransient<IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
    }
```

Controller class

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductController(ClothingContext clothingContext)
    {
        productRepository = ProductRepository.GetInstance(clothingContext);
    }
    // GET: api/<ProductController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(productRepository.GetObjectList());
    }

    // GET api/<ProductController>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}" ,Name ="GetProductById")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(productRepository.GetObjectById(id));
    }

    // POST api/<ProductController>/a
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            productRepository.InsertObject(product);
            scope.Complete();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { ID = product.Id }, product);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/<ProductController>/5
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        if(product != null)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                productRepository.UpdateObject(product);
                scope.Complete();
                return new OkResult();
            }
        }
        return new NoContentResult();
    }

    // DELETE api/<ProductController>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        productRepository.DeleteObject(id);
        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

**The problem is, whenever I doing a POST or GET request I get ObjectDisposedException: [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxxJy.jpg)**

Comment: Context added with `AddDbContext` by default is scoped ... and for uknown reason you are caching it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a repository package and applying Generic Repository Pattern.

Well that's your problem right there. I wish people would stop wrapping Entity Framework in a crippling repository pattern.

You're hiding functionality behind a custom, undocumented wrapper that nobody except you understands, that does not offer any additional functionality, that does not offer many of the stuff that Entity Framework does (`IEnumerable<T> GetObjectList()` does not support paging nor sorting nor filtering for example and will break as soon as you build anything other than a TODO app with like ten records) and Entity Framework's `DbSet<T>` **ALREADY IS** a repository pattern.

And why are you suddenly creating transactions within your controller? Shouldn't the repository abstract the database access away?

So your solution would be to remove `IRepository` and `Repository` and just inject your `ClothingContext` where you need it, and you're done.

If you insist on the misguided repository pattern approach, your additional problem is caused by wanting to provide the repository as a kind-of-singleton. This holds on to a DbContext that your DI framework has already disposed.

Remove the singleton code.

Comment: Thank you brother. Yes the code and approach is bad. And I removed singleton it started to work. Thank you.